# send to the nearest node in a wireless network

Tags: omnet++

In a wireless simulation with `omnet++ inet 3.6`, how can I manage sensor nodes to send the packets to the nearest mobile nodes? There are several sensor and mobile nodes in the field and thus cannot choose a specific destination like `*.host[*].udpApp[0].destAddresses="host[0]"`

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific needs in the behavior of the application you are using, you need to implement that application. I assume you want to send UDP traffic (as TCP is connection oriented). Take a look at UdpBasicApp and modify it in a way that instead of reading the destination address once during the initialization, it must calculate the destination IP on each new packet (based on the position of nodes).

Comment: thanks Mr @Rudy. when I run the simulation, nodes send data to all others while I set in ini file a specific destination. Is it usual or should I change the UdpBasicApp?